# Fetch only 1 level in a OneToOne relation with same table

Tags: java, openjpa

I searched on the web but cannot filter out the solution. I get pointed to Spring and Hibernate but I am only interested in the solution with `OpenJPA`.

I have a table in which I store the taxonomy tree. The key is the `TAXON_ID` and it is linked with its parent through the `PARENT_ID`. I created the following `DTO` named `TaxonDto` (I left out the fields that are of no importance):

```
@Column(name="PARENT_ID")
private Long      parentId;
@Column(name="RANG", length=3, nullable=false)
private String    rang;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="TAXON_ID", nullable=false, unique=true, updatable=false)
private Long      taxonId;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=TaxonDto.class, orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName="TAXON_ID", updatable=false, insertable=false)
private TaxonDto  parent;
```

My problem lies in the `@OneToOne`. I did a test with `FetchType.EAGER` but then the size of the returned data is 3x bigger as with `FetchType.LAZY` since I get all parents below the taxon. What I want is that the parent is fetched when the rang is a specific value namely `oso`. I can live with a solution where the parent is not recursively filled, the parent of the parent should not be returned.

Is this possible and if so how can I do this? I have seen *discriminators*, *fetchgroup* and *subclass `DTO`* but it leaves me clueless.

Comment: He who never tries anything remains clueless.

Comment: He who fails after a few days of trying should ask a question :-)

Comment: I don't see says of trying here.

Comment: In the entity class you can implement a method annotated with PostLoad. Check the rang and load parent if relevant.

Comment: Had not come across this. I tried it and it worked. If you make an answer out of it the I will accept it so you get rewarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the entity class you can implement a method annotated with @PostLoad. Check the rang and load parent if relevant.

Like this:

```
private TaxonDto getPostLoadTaxon() {
  return parent;
}

@PostLoad
private void onPostLoad() {
  if (getRang().equals("oso")) {
    getPostLoadTaxon();
  }
}
```